# Server side encryption on Amazon S3 with JCloud

Tags: amazon-s3, jclouds

If I understand correctly right now it is not possible to use aws s3 server side encryption ("x-amz-server-side-encryption") with jcloud api? If that is not the case how one is supposed to trigger server side encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jclouds does not yet support S3 server-side encryption, tracked by [JCLOUDS-533](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-533).